# Can't use Spinner.setSelection from Database

Tags: android, android-spinner

I make application can input data from spinner into database when user open activity spinner retrieve data from DB and then if the user change value of spinner, its refresh the spinner (In My case if user click the edit button, data not match with database) how can I fix this?

This is my code :

```
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.editfpp);
            getAlamatBill(id);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
      spinnerprovinsibill.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String kodeprovinsi = helper.getRefprovinsi(spinnerprovinsibill.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    ambilKabupaten(kodeprovinsi, spinnerkabupatenbill);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

            spinnerkabupatenbill.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String kodekabupaten = helper.getRefkabupaten(spinnerkabupatenbill.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    ambilKecamatan(kodekabupaten, spinnerkecamatanbill);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

    }

        private void ambilKecamatan(String kodekabupaten, Spinner spinnerkecamatanbill) {
            List<String> data = helper.getKecamatan(kodekabupaten);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_background, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerkecamatanbill.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        private void ambilKabupaten(String kodeprovinsibill, Spinner spinnerkabupatenbill) {
            List<String> data = helper.getKabupaten(kodeprovinsibill);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_background, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerkabupatenbill.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

   private void ambilProvinsiPilihan(Spinner spinner, String namaprovinsi, String kabupaten, String kecamatan, String kelurahan){
        List<String> data = helper.getProvinsi();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_background, data);
        dataadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataadapter);
        int posisi = dataadapter.getPosition(namaprovinsi);
        spinner.setSelection(posisi);
        System.out.println("hasil = " + helper.getRefkabupaten(kabupaten) + " " + helper.getRefkecamatan(kecamatan));

    }

private void getAlamatBill(String id) {
        try {
            System.out.println("persiapan data: " + id);
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(helper.getAlamatShip(id));
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
            String alamat = object.getString("alamat");
            String kdpos = object.getString("kdpos");
            String kelurahan = object.getString("kelurahan");
            String kecamatan = object.getString("kecamatan");
            String kabupaten = object.getString("kabupaten");
            String provinsi = object.getString("provinsi");
            String kota = object.getString("kota");
            ambilProvinsiPilihanShip(spinnerprovinsiship, provinsi, kabupaten, kecamatan, kelurahan);
            ambilKotaPilihan(spinnerkotaship, kota);
            edalamatship.setText(alamat);
            edkodeposship.setText(kdpos);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get vs what you expect?

Comment: Hai @cricket_007 thanks for answer,  I hope I can set spinner from value from database SQLite, but I get my spinner refreshed by `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`, I want the spinner refreshed only when user change spinner.

Comment: I understand what you want, but what exactly is wrong with your code? What is happening now that is different than what you expect?

Comment: I can't identify whats wrong in my code and yes that is different with what I want.